# Introducing php variables in column graphic

Tags: php, javascript, variables

How can I do to introduce php variables in building a column chart, line and pie?

```
<?php $numero = 9; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mes_I = "<?p h p echo $numero; ?>";
        var chart;
            $(function container_V () {
                var chart;
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container_V'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Média de Utilização de Animais'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ["mes_III", "mes_II", "mes_I"]
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                var s;
                                if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                                    s = ''+
                                        this.point.name +': '+ this.y +'%';
                                } else {
                                    s = ''+
                                        this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                                }
                                return s;
                            }
                        },
                        labels: {
                            items: [{
                                html: 'Utilização',
                                style: {
                                    left: '40px',
                                    top: '8px',
                                    color: 'black'
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        series: [{
                            type: 'column',
                            name: 'Mouse',
                            color: 'white',
                            data: [mes_I]
                        }, {
                            type: 'spline',
                            name: 'Average',
                            data: [3, 2.67, 3],
                            marker: {
                                lineWidth: 3,
                                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                                fillColor: 'black'
                            }
                        }, {
                            type: 'pie',
                            name: 'Total consumption',
                            data: [{
                                name: 'LABCET',
                                y: 10,
                                color: '#006400'
                            }, {
                                name: 'LPEP',
                                y: 19,
                                color: '#00BFFF'
                            }],
                            center: [70, 75],
                            size: 100,
                            showInLegend: false,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }]
                    });
                }); 
            });

    </script>
```

The variable mes_I ok, containing the value '9 '. However, when I type in the given series, it does not appear.

Comment: you have spaces in php word and you do not have to use " just <?php echo $variable;?>

Comment: Are those spaces in "p h p" intentional?

Comment: @StackOverfolow: no, it should be `<?php echo json_encode($variable) ?>` to guarantee producing syntactically valid JS.

Comment: @MarcB: Why is `json_encode` necessary? `$numero` is just a number.

Comment: @marcel: good habit to get into. one day you'll dump out a string and kill the script block because the string had a stray `'` or something in it. json_encode adds microscopic overhead for "simple" data types, and will save your butt on complex ones.

Answer (score 1):

The best  way to encode PHP variables for use in JS is to `json_encode` them. That will take care of numbers, encoding strings and putting quotes around them, and also deal with nested objects. May not be strictly needed in this case because it's a number, but it's a good habit to get into.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mes_I = <?php echo json_encode($numero); ?>;
```

In your sample code you had

```
<? p h p
```

Instead of

```
<?php
```

Comment: I do not see the need of an answer to such a question... It should be downvoted... There are a lot more interesting and true unanswerd questions in this website than some syntax errors...

Comment: @StackOverfolow You're free to downvote it. I'm trying to teach the OP a few tricks